# IE: Removing readonly doesn't work until clicked

Tags: javascript, html

In this html and javascript, the readonly is removed when "txtAddName" input box is mouse-clicked.  However, if you tab over from the first field, the readonly attribute isn't removed.

This only happens with IE.  It works fine with Chrome.

Since I'm stuck using IE, does anyone have a workaround for this?

```js
function enableName() {
  document.getElementById('txtAddName').removeAttribute('readonly');
}
```

```html
Employee Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='text' id='txtAddEmpNum' value='' onblur='enableName()'>
<br> Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input readonly type='text' id='txtAddName' value='' />
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you have `value=''/`. Remove the forward-slash `/` character.

Comment: @Dai It still does not work in IE with the slash removed

Comment: @Dai  Errant Copy/paste error.  It doesn't affect the issue at hand and the extraneous slash isn't in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById('txtAddName').addEventListener("focus", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("txtAddEmpNum").value.trim().length > 0) this.removeAttribute('readOnly');
    this.select();
  })
})
```

```html
Employee Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='text' id='txtAddEmpNum' value=''>
<br> Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input readonly type='text' id='txtAddName' value='' />
```

Comment: this.select() worked.  Thank you!